# Query produced from string concatenation fails with `Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE`

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to insert values in two tables in the same time. The first value is integer type 
*Example* 
[image]

I am giving an input like **$5000** this is my first value after i am converting the this value
`quotvalue = Val(((finalpayment.Text) / 100) * 2)`

Then I want to insert this two values first in *textbox* and second is the *quotvalue*

I am using  **SQL server 2008** there i have two tables
[image]

Among these two table I am inputting the values in **Project_Progress** and converting the value **final_payment** after I want to insert this value in **Emplyee** table column **insentives**

This is my sample code in **VB.NET**

```
myconnection = New SqlConnection(strconnection)
        myconnection.Open()
        quotvalue = Val(((finalpayment.Text) / 100) * 2)
        myquery &= "insert into Project_Progress (Project_id,client_id, ex_id, final_payment, dateof_payment, stattus) values('" & txtprjectid.Text & "','" & clientid.Text & "','" & exid.Text & "','" & finalpayment.Text & "', '" & dateofquot.Text & "', '" & txtstatus.Text & "')"
        myquery &= "insert into Emplyee (insentive) values('" & quotvalue & "') WHERE  Project_Progress.ex_id = Emplyee.Emp_ID "
        mycommand = New SqlCommand(myquery, myconnection)
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myconnection.Close()
```

After executing the code this problem is occurring

[image]

please help & suggest me what should i do

Comment: I don't familiar with vb.net but from the look of sql query I think it goes in weird direction, afaik that "insert values() where" statement shouldn't be valid.

Comment: you should either "insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3) values (val1,val2,val3)" or "insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from another_table"

Comment: First and foremost **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)**, you are asking for trouble if you don't. The reason for your error though is that you can't use `WHERE` when using `INSERT .. VALUES ...` - what exactly are you trying to achieve with your second insert?

Comment: String Concatenation. Bobby Tables. Don't. *NO* amount of quoting can fix such code. A single `'` in any of the inputs is enough to result in a bad query. Use parameterized queries instead. Once you do, you'll see that nothing separates the two queries

Comment: Furthermore, don't use `Val`, ever. *Parse and validate* all inputs into the appropriate type,, using the *appropriate* culture first, then use it for calculations. Different countries use different decimal separators, with most of Europe using `,` instead of `.`. What would your code do with an input of `1,000` ? What about a date of `13/12/2017`? Or `13.12.2017`?

Comment: I want to insert the converted value of final_payment in the Emplyee database with my second query that's my main point but it doesn't happen

Comment: @PronabRoy nor will it ever. Use *parameterized queries*. Parse the input into the appropriate types. Don't use concatenation. Separate the queries with `;`. There are hundreds of duplicate questions

Comment: @PronabRoy Furthermore, you can't have a WHERE in a simple INSERT. It doesn't make any sense to do so. If you wanted to joing with another table to get an ID, you should have a `FROM .. INNER JOIN ..` clause, although your query doesn't use any data from other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two statements (two inserts) in the same string/variable (myquery).

You should execute one first, and then the other.

Apart from that, take a look at 'Parametrized queries', 'cause your code is prone to SQL injection

Comment: There's no problem with batching multiple queries. As long as they *are* separated